# React Range Slider works but the Slider Button cannot be moved

Tags: reactjs, input, event-handling

I'm trying to create a simple range slider to React with iOS styles for a demo. It is working, the color is changing for the bar when I drag it fine. But the Slider Button cannot be moved. It is just stuck at one position. I'm new at this and pretty sure it must be something small that is being ignored but I'm not sure. Any help will be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
export class RangeSwitch extends Component {
  onChangeHandler = e => {
    const initValue = e.target.value;
    const min = e.target.min;
    const max = e.target.max;

    let value = (initValue - min) / (max - min);
    e.target.style.backgroundImage = [
      '-webkit-gradient(',
      'linear, ',
      'left top, ',
      'right top, ',
      'color-stop(' + value + ', #007aff), ',
      'color-stop(' + value + ', #b8b7b8)',
      ')',
    ].join('');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <SwitchContainer>
        <input
          type="range"
          min="1"
          max="100"
          value="20"
          id="range"
          onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
        />
      </SwitchContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To un-stick the slider button, you need to remove `value="20"` from the `<input>` element inside `<SwitchContainer>`

Comment/Comment-out `value="20"` and notice the slider button being stuck/freed.